# Why does a pyarrow backend df need more RAM than a numpy backend?

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

I am reading a large parquet file with int, string and date columns.
When using `dtype_backend="pyarrow"` instead of default `dtype_backend="numpy_nullable"`, I get 15.6 GB instead of 14.6 GB according to `df.info()`.
Furthermore, I experienced even larger relative overhead using pyarrow for other datasets.

code:

```
pd.read_parquet("df.parquet", dtype_backend="numpy_nullable").info()
```

> dtypes: Int16(1), Int32(2), datetime64ns, UTC, string(1),
> timedelta64ns memory usage: 14.6 GB

```
pd.read_parquet("df.parquet", dtype_backend="pyarrow").info()
```

> dtypes: duration[ns]pyarrow, int16pyarrow,
> int32pyarrow, stringpyarrow, timestamp[ns,
> tz=UTC]pyarrow memory usage: 15.6 GB

Is this the **expected behaviour** or do I have to tweak other parameters as well?

I'm using pandas[parquet] ~= 2.1.3

Comment: When using a tiny dataset like titanic it's 90kb vs. 102kb --> even 10% increase e.g. using:
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/master/titanic.csv"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `pd.DataFrame.info` gives you the shallow representation of memory when using numpy as a backend. So it won't give you an accurate representation of memory usage for string columns.

On the other hand, reported memory usage for pyarrow is always accurate.

You should use `memory_usage(deep=True)`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["abc", "efg"]})

(
    df.memory_usage().sum(),
    df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum(),
    df.astype({"col1": "string[pyarrow]"}).memory_usage().sum(),
    df.astype({"col1": "string[pyarrow]"}).memory_usage(deep=True).sum(),
)
```

Gives me: 144, 248, 142, 142

Comment: this helps a lot! Actual numpy-backend size is more than 30GB. Seems like I'll use pyarrow-backend more often!